# assign updated global values to overriden methods in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to kotlin  and i have a global variable and i'm trying to update it in the overriden method but it keeps saying unresolved reference.. but as you see I have declared in the above both the variables and methods.

```
     class FilterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private fun setPrice(value: Int) {

        }

        var priceUpdateFloat: Float= 0.0f

        object pricelistener : OnRangeChangedListener {
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(view: RangeSeekBar?, isLeft: Boolean) {


                //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onRangeChanged(view: RangeSeekBar, leftValue: Float, rightValue: Float, isFromUser: Boolean) {

                priceUpdateFloat = leftValue  //error here unresolved reference
                setPrice(leftValue) //error here unresolved reference

                Log.d(TAG, "left value is" + view.leftSeekBar + "isFromUser_" + isFromUser)

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(view: RangeSeekBar?, isLeft: Boolean) {
                //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }


    }

    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_filter)


  price_seek_bar1.setOnRangeChangedListener(
                pricelistener
        )

    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
val pricelistener = object : OnRangeChangedListener {
...
}
```

Comment: there's a red line below onRangeChanged overriden method. that says can not find this variable "priceUpdateFloat". and I want this variable to set some filelds there.

Comment: just try it. `object pricelistener : OnRangeChangedListener { }` is new class. and it's not inner class. if you want change field of FilterActivity, you should declare it as a variable. hmmm Did you want to make inner class? `object` cannot be `inner class`.

Comment: `inner class pricelistener : OnRangeChangedListener { }` will work with you..

Comment: That's all I wanted. Thanks! :)